# Extracción de variables de una API en Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

Quisiera extraer las variables longitud y latitud para después agregarlas a una nueva petición, ¿cómo podría hacerlo o de que manera puedo modificar el código para realizar la extracción?

```
//variables globales
const n=navigator;
const d=document;
//variables para funcion de Api
const key= 'q3IrVyHwcfzzigxTgh1CWz';
const lenguaje = 'en-us';
//generar longitud y latitud
    const succes = (position) =>{
        let coords = position.coords;
        let latitud=coords.latitude;
        let longitud=coords.longitude;
        d.getElementById("latitud").innerHTML = latitud;
        d.getElementById("longitud").innerHTML = longitud;
        console.log(longitud);
        console.log(latitud);
        return latitud,longitud;
    };

    const error =(err) => {
        console.log(err);
    };
    n.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succes, error);
//extraer latitud  longitud
    

//API GEOLOCATION
const getKey = async (city) => {
    const UrlApi= 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search';
    const requestUrl =UrlApi + `?apikey=${key}&q=${latitud},${longitud}&language=${lenguaje}&details=false&toplevel=false`; 
    console.log(requestUrl);
    const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
    const data = await response.json(); 
    return data;
    };
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código como texto, [formateado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) por favor? Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: Espero que esa no sea una `key` válida. Por favor. Edita tu preguntas. Tus credenciales son privadas y no debes exponerlas.

Comment: Puedes declarar las variables donde tienes las variables globales y en el método "success" las seteas con el valor que recibes. Luego en la función getKey ya tendrías acceso al valor de latitud y longitud

Comment: Avisa a quien corresponda que expusiste una api key para que la cambien.

Answer (score 0):

Podría intentar lo siguiente:

```js
// Variables globales
const n=navigator;
const d=document;

// Variables para funcion de API
const api= 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search';
const key= 'xxxxxx';
const lang = 'en-us';


// Coordenadas
let lat;
let lng;

// Extraer coordenadas
let getLocation = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  n.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(([ coords ]) => { // Desestructura para acceder a las coordenadas
    // Asigna las coordenadas
    lat = coords.latitude;
    lng = coords.longitude;
    
    // Muestra las coordenadas en HTML
    d.getElementById("latitud").innerHTML = lat;
    d.getElementById("longitud").innerHTML = lng;
    
    // Resuleve la promesa con las coordenadas
    resolve([lat, lng]);
  }, error => {
    // En caso de error o no tener permisos
    reject(error.message);
  });
});

// API Geolocation
const getKey = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const url = `${api}?apikey=${key}&q=${lat},${lng}&language=${lang}&details=false&toplevel=false`;
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    // En caso de éxito retorna la petición formateada
    resolve(response.json());
  }).catch(error => {
    // En caso de no conectar al servidor o recibir un estado de error
    reject(error);
  });
});

// Sincroniza las peticiones: primere obtiene la localización y luego lanza la petición al servidor
Promise.all([getLocation, getKey]).then(values => {
 // Aquí iría la logica de que se cumplieron ambas promesas
  console.log(values); // [[1.111,2.222], { key: 123 }];
}).catch(error => {
    // Si ocurre algún error en alguna de las 2 promesas
  console.log(error)
});
```

- [Desestructuración de objetos](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectAndArrayMatchingDefaultValues)
- [Documentación Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Documentación Sincronizar Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)